# GUI for application with and without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, qt, wireshark

I was running `wireshark` when I realized that executing it using `sudo` and without `sudo` gave me a different user interface.

When running using `sudo`, it gives me nice sized icon and text. But running it without `sudo` makes the icon and some of the text so big.

[image: Wireshark with sudo]

I've also check for `Packet Tracer` and it gave me the same behavior. After some check, I realized that both Wireshark and Packet Tracer are using Qt.

Why does this happen? And how do I get the nice interface (like when running it with `sudo`), when running it without `sudo`?

NB: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with default desktop environment